# Windows: loop through text batch

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, batch-file

I use the software MyFFVideoConverter. I would like to run a batch script.
My code looks like this:

```
-i intro.jpg -i <input_file> -codec:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -acodec copy -strict experimental -movflags faststart -t 00:10:10.00 <output_file>
```

It works but i would like to use a `mylist.txt` command instead `-i intro.jpg`. The script should pick only the first entry in the `mylist.txt` file, for example `intro1.jpg`, and delete the first entry afterwards. The next time the script would use `intro2.jpg` and delete this new first entry and so on.

Comment: The mylist.txt would be look like this: intro1.jpg intro2.jpg intro3.jpg and so on. One entry for every line.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your current command like that:

```
for line in $(cat mylist.txt); do MyFFVideoConverter ... -i $line ; done
```

(replace the ... by all your other options)

This loop will run your command once per line in `mylist.txt`, each time using the content of the line as parameter of the `-i` switch.

This does not delete anything from the `mylist.txt` file. You can remove it altogether at the end with `rm`.

If you really need just to pick the first line and remove it, then:

```
line = $(head -1 mylist.txt)
MyFFVideoConverter ... -i $line
```

and then to remove the first line from `mylist.txt` I defer you to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96226/delete-first-line-of-a-file which gives a bunch of solutions.

All the above suppose your lines (file names) do not have spaces in them, or characters interpreted by the shell (|, &, etc.). If that is the case you will need to be more cautious, and protect things with quotes.

Comment: It did not work. The following script worked but it has always the same picture as background image: 
`C:\VideoConverter\Applications\ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 0.1 -i pic004.jpg -i %~d1%~p1%~n1.mp3 -codec:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -acodec copy -strict experimental -movflags faststart -t 00:10:10.00 -f mp4 %~d1%~p1%~n1.mp4`

Comment: I tried this: `C:\VideoConverter\Applications\ffmpeg.exe for line in $(cat mylist.txt); -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 0.1 -i %~d1%~p1%~n1.mp3 -codec:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -acodec copy -strict experimental -movflags faststart -t 00:10:10.00 -f mp4 %~d1%~p1%~n1.mp4 -i $line ; done` but i had no success

Comment: I tried it with this script: https://dmeresources.com/index.php/professional-community/news-blogs/932-batch-processing-with-ffmpeg-on-windows I use only ffmpeg.exe from the myvideoconverter folder now.

Comment: I was not aware you were on Windows, sorry. My answer is for Unix based systems. No idea how to make it run under Windows but I am sure you can do loops there too.

Comment: I found this to loop through text: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html , but i dont know how the code has to be look like in my case.